# secondary axis with geom_raster ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following example data and need to plot it twice one using yr, mo, Var and long and one using yr, mo, var and lat. I need to use secondary axis for long and lat so I can track annual variability.
I have tried several ways but no success. Any idea please.

```
month <- month.abb[c(1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11)] # no summer 
month <- ordered(month, month.abb)
yr=  seq(1980, 2005, by = 1)
Var <- runif(26, min=-29, max=32)
longitude <- runif(26, min=37, max=81)
latitude <-runif(26, min=4, max=67) 
#Set the dataframe
df <- data.frame(month, yr, Var, longitude, latitude)

## for Long

normalizer <- max(df$yr) / max(df$longitude)


df %>%
  arrange(month) %>%
  mutate(month = factor(month, 
                     levels=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr", "May", 
                           "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov","Dec"))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_raster( aes(x=month, y=yr,fill = Var))+
  geom_point( aes(x= month, y=longitude/normalizer),size = 2)+
  #geom_point( aes(x= month, y= (5- longitude/10),size = 2))+
  scale_y_continuous("yr", sec.axis = sec_axis(trans= ~.*normalizer,name = "Long"))+
  #scale_y_continuous("yr", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 5 -.*10, name = "Long"))+
  theme_bw()+ 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c("purple4","blue","dodgerblue","lightcyan","olivedrab1", "yellow","red","#7F0000","deeppink"), 
                       breaks = breaks3) +
  xlab("") +  ylab("")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `scale_fill` command which refers to breaks3 that are not defined and you uncomment the `geom_point` your code produces a plot with secondary axis:

```
library(tidyverse)
month <- month.abb[c(1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11)] # no summer 
month <- ordered(month, month.abb)
yr <-  seq(1980, 2005, by = 1)
Var <- runif(26, min=-29, max=32)
longitude <- runif(26, min=37, max=81)
latitude <-runif(26, min=4, max=67) 

#Set the dataframe
df <- data.frame(month, yr, Var, longitude, latitude)

# for Long
normalizer <- max(df$yr) / max(df$longitude)

df %>%
     arrange(month) %>%
     mutate(month = factor(month, 
                           levels=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr", "May", 
                                    "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov","Dec"))) %>%
     ggplot() +
     geom_raster( aes(x=month, y=yr,fill = Var))+
     geom_point( aes(x= month, y=longitude/normalizer),size = 2)+
     geom_point( aes(x= month, y= (5- longitude/10),size = 2))+
     scale_y_continuous("yr", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 5 -.*10, name = "Long"))
```

Is this your desired output?
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. My codes already give similar results. I'm looking to for a plot that has two y-axis with different scale one for years and one for longitude.